# Pulling salary from HTML job specs of differing structure and salary notation

Tags: python, regex, xpath, grep, lxml

I'm looking to pull salary information from job specs in a generic a fashion as possible (taking into the account the multitude of ways salary can be specified (with and without the word 'Salary' preceeding it, with our without trailing zeros, ranges etc.)

Taking three different job specs, I grab the HTML with `urllib2`, then perform an initial case-insensitive `grep` for the word 'salary in each'. The results vary widely (excuse the less-than-pretty pastes from Jupyter):

```
In [52]:

urllib2
Out[52]:
<module 'urllib2' from '/Users/Evan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc'>
In [82]:
```

**Case #1**

```
reponse = urllib2_urlopen('http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/453/cro-manager/london/')
In [83]:

content = reponse.read()
In [84]:

save_html('salarygrep1', content)
In [59]:

!grep -i salary salarygrep1.html
!grep -i salary salarygrep1.html
  <dt class="field_salary">Salary</dt>
  <dd class="value_salary">
In [86]:

with open('salarygrep1.html') as s:
    for line in s:
        if 'salary' in line.lower():
            print line
  <dt class="field_salary">Salary</dt>

  <dd class="value_salary">

In [79]:
```

**Case #2**

```
reponse = urllib2_urlopen('http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/475/ovo-telesales-agent/bristol/')
In [80]:

content = reponse.read()
In [81]:

save_html('salarygrep2', content)
In [63]:

!grep -i salary salarygrep2.html
  <dt class="field_salary">Salary</dt>
  <dd class="value_salary">
    Salary: �18,000 + benefits & competitive commission scheme; OTE range: �20,500 - �30,000
In [87]:

with open('salarygrep2.html') as s:
    for line in s:
        if 'salary' in line.lower():
            print line
​
  <dt class="field_salary">Salary</dt>

  <dd class="value_salary">

    Salary: �18,000 + benefits & competitive commission scheme; OTE range: �20,500 - �30,000

In [88]:
```

**Case #3**

```
reponse = urllib2_urlopen('https://gs7.globalsuccessor.com/centrica02/tpl_centrica02.asp?s=4A515F4E5A565B1A&jobid=48490,2356610248&key=21798303&c=028859657862&pagestamp=dbykvxmmwfnblykbqc')
In [89]:

content = reponse.read()
In [90]:

save_html('salarygrep3', content)
In [67]:

!grep -i salary salarygrep3.html
!grep -i salary salarygrep3.html
<p id="igSoundBite"><em><div>Salary: &#163;28-&#163;38K depending on experience</div></em></p><h3 id="igJobDesc0">Job Description</h3><p><div>Assistant Product Development Manager </div>
In [95]:

with open('salarygrep3.html') as s:
    for line in s:
        if 'salary' in line.lower():
            print line
<p id="igSoundBite"><em><div>Salary: &#163;28-&#163;38K depending on experience</div></em></p><h3 id="igJobDesc0">Job Description</h3><p><div>Assistant Product Development Manager </div>

In [70]:
```

**Case #4**

```
reponse = urllib2_urlopen('http://jobs.emounlimited.com/senior-digital-project-manager/')
In [71]:

content = reponse.read()
In [72]:

save_html('salarygrep4', content)
In [94]:

!grep -i salary salarygrep4.html
In [92]:

with open('salarygrep4.html') as s:
    for line in s:
        if 'salary' in line.lower():
            print line
In [ ]:
```

​

- ​In case #1, the actual salary is in a different `<div>`, and doesn't
  get picked up at all.
- In case #2, the salary does get detected but (i) it's a range that will need to be handled and (ii) There are non-ASCII currency characters (UK £).
- In case #3, the salary also gets detected but (i) it's a range that will need to be handled and (ii) There are non-ASCII currency characters (UK £).
- In case for, because a salary is specified but the the word 'Salary' is not mentioned, nothing gets detected.

Is it unreasonable to believe that given the wide variation in page design and in salary specification, that a one-size-fits-all (or one-size-fits-most) regex or combination of regexes might do the trick? If not, how would I go about constructing it/them? Or indeed, is there a Python approach to this that might rely less on regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea:

- pass the HTML of the page through the `BeautifulSoup`
- get the text of the `body` element (we are not interested in the rest)
- using regular expressions, select amounts

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/453/cro-manager/london/",
    "http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/475/ovo-telesales-agent/bristol/",
    "https://gs7.globalsuccessor.com/centrica02/tpl_centrica02.asp?s=4A515F4E5A565B1A&jobid=48490,2356610248&key=21798303&c=028859657862&pagestamp=dbykvxmmwfnblykbqc",
    "http://jobs.emounlimited.com/senior-digital-project-manager/"
]

money_pattern = re.compile(ur"($|£)([0-9.,]+K?)(?:\s*-\s*(?:$|£)*([0-9.,]+K?)*)*")
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    text = soup.body.text

    print("URL: " + url)
    for currency, amount1, amount2 in money_pattern.findall(text):
        if not amount1 and not amount2:
            continue

        if not amount2:
            print("Single amount found: %s, currency: %s" % (amount1, currency))
        else:
            print("Range found: %s - %s, currency: %s" % (amount1, amount2, currency) )
    print("------")
```

Output:

```
URL: http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/453/cro-manager/london/
Range found: 40,000 - 50,000, currency: £
------
URL: http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/475/ovo-telesales-agent/bristol/
Single amount found: 18,000, currency: £
Range found: 20,500 - 30,000, currency: £
------
URL: https://gs7.globalsuccessor.com/centrica02/tpl_centrica02.asp?s=4A515F4E5A565B1A&jobid=48490,2356610248&key=21798303&c=028859657862&pagestamp=dbykvxmmwfnblykbqc
Range found: 28 - 38K, currency: £
------
URL: http://jobs.emounlimited.com/senior-digital-project-manager/
Range found: 36 - 40,000, currency: £
------
```

Hope this would at least get you started.

Comment: That's one heck of a regex. Interesting that BeautifulSoup manages to bypass the character encoding issues around the **£**. Is it the `html.parser` that achieves this?

Comment: @Pyderman it's actually the `.text` of the `response` and `BeautifulSoup` itself :)